# Ant Copying Empty Directories

Tags: ant, copy

I am still very new to ant and, although I know coldfusion, I don't know very much about java conventions, but I know that ant is built using java conventions.  That being said I am working on an ant process to copy a project to a temp folder, change some code in the project, and then push the temp directory up to an FTP.  I am trying to exclude all of my git, eclipse, and ant files from the copy so that my testing platform doesn't get cluttered.  I setup a target to do the copy, but it seems that Ant not only is ignoring my excludes (which I am sure I wrote wrong), but it is only copying top level directories and files.  No recursive copy.  My current target is:

```
<target name="moveToTemp" depends="init">
    <delete dir="./.ant/temp" />
    <mkdir dir="./.ant/temp" />
    <copy todir="./.ant/temp">
        <fileset dir=".">
            <include name="*" />
            <exclude name=".*/**" />
            <exclude name=".*" />
            <exclude name="build.xml" />
            <exclude name="settings.xml" />
            <exclude name="WEB-INF/**" />
        </fileset>
        <filterset>
            <filter token="set(environment='design')" value="set(environment='testing')" />
        </filterset>
    </copy>
</target>
```

I know that I am not doing my excludes right, but I don't know what I am doing wrong with them.  I see double asterisks (**) used all the time in Ant but I can't figure out

Comment: Which excludes does it seem to ignore? The ./'s are unnecessary and possibly break those. have you tried ant -d?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default an Ant fileset will (recursively) include all files under the specified directory, equivalent to:

```
<include name="**/*" />
```

That's the implicit include.  If you supply an include, it overrides the implicit one.

Your include

```
<include name="*" />
```

Says '*match any file in the fileset directory*', but that excludes traversal of subdirectories, hence your issue.  Only files and the top-level directories are being copied.

See [Patterns](http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#patterns) in the Ant docs for directory-based tasks: `**` matches any directory tree (zero or more directories).

For your case you should be able to simply remove the 'include', so that the implicit 'include all' applies.

Suggest you also investigate the [`defaultexcludes` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/defaultexcludes.html), which lets you set up this sort of thing once for the whole project.

Answer (score 0):

Responding to the title of the question. You can include copy of empty directories as follows. (**includeemptydirs** attribute)

Example:

```
    <copy includeemptydirs="true" todir="${directory}${file.separator}sentinel_files">
        <fileset dir="${basedir}${file.separator}sentinel_files"/>
    </copy>
```

Use the documentation provided in:

https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html